# Cannot insert tilde in Eclipse for C/C++

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

In Eclipse for C/C++ on Windows 10, I cannot insert the tilde symbol '~' which works fine in other applications.
I'm on a french keyboard, so I type Alt Gr + '~' to access it ('~' key is also the one for 'é' and '2').
I saw similar problems with curly braces or asterisks, resolved by deactivating a given shortcut, but I saw none for tildes.

I searched in the shortcuts of eclipse, but found none using '~' key with alt gr (even none with '~' key and alt or ctrl or something else).

Thank you in advance

Comment: On which operating system? For instance, on Windows there is a shortcut by default to change the keyboard layout for the active/foreground application only, which you might have accidentally used.

Comment: Yes, sorry, and thanks for the answer. I am on windows 10. I didn't know there was a shortcut for that.The thing is, the others keys of my keyboard works as expected, and even by restarting eclipse or rebooting windows, nothing changes. And in the settings, the option let me set a different input method for each app window in unchecked.

Comment: Same problem, french keyboard, windows 10. Using a different editor. And for some days I cannot write a tilde. It works on other programs.

Comment: I haven't found a solution... I keep copy pasting for now, i don't have that much binary inversions to do now that my drivers are done

Comment: Same problem, Turkish keyboard: AltGr + ü should output tilde.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>keys 0 to 9 from numeric pad to compose values from 1 to 255 or 0128 to 0255</kbd> ([list of codes and corresponding characters](https://www.alt-codes.net/)), it's possible to enter a few characters which are not available on the keyboard:

- `~` : use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>
- `` ` `` : use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>

Comment: Worked out perfectly, and can be used with other IDEs too I suppose ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me on my Turkish Q layout, in which `AltGr+ü` produces tilde. It is to create a new keyboard layout and remove the dead key attribute from this key, which has the added benefit of removing this annoying "feature" of requiring two key presses to get these symbols. A detailed solution is at: https://superuser.com/a/414415/351077

Somehow the language tray icon displays the wrong language ("ENG") for the newly created layout even though the properties in the layout editor are correct, but I don't mind.